# PHP cURL Fatal error: Uncaught Exception Error

Tags: php, xml

I am attempting to use PHP cURL to retrieve an XML file on a remote server. When using PHP v5.5 on my personal computer (using Windows/MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) as a compiler) and running the following code in a browser, the file aqi.xml saves to the folder where my PHP file resides and the only word "Downloaded!" is printed to the browser.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fileUrl = 'http://www.southwestohioair.org/UserFiles/Servers/Server_3788196/File/EnvironmentalServices/AirQuality/Feeds/feed_aqi.xml';
$saveTo = 'aqi.xml';

$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');
if($fp === false){
    throw new Exception('Could not open: ' . $saveTo);
}
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($statusCode == 200){
    echo 'Downloaded!';
} else{
    echo "Status Code: " . $statusCode;
}
```

When I run the same PHP script on my web server (using PHP v7.1.18 on Apache), however, the following is printed to the browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Failed connect to www.southwestohioair.org:80; Connection timed out in /storage/ssd5/010/1116010/public_html/sandbox/curlaqitest.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/010/1116010/public_html/sandbox/curlaqitest.php on line 25
```

Is there any reason or setting I'm missing that prevents me from successfully retrieving the file on my Apache server when it successfully runs on my local machine?

Comment: hey your url not responding

Comment: *"Failed connect to www.southwestohioair.org:80; Connection timed out"* -- if that remote site is online and responding to requests from your local PC, maybe there's a firewall blocking outgoing requests from your webserver. Check with your webhost.